# Deploy solution MSBuild script for multilpe Sharepoint solutions

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, msbuild, sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint and the project I am working on has 11 seperate solutions.

For me to get a site up and running I have to go in and build then deploy the 11 solutions.

I want to automate this using MSBuild can, has anyone done this before and have you got example code please?

Answer (score 1):

Create an msbuild project file that contains something like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
     <SolutionItem Include="./Solution1.snl" />
     <SolutionItem Include="./Solution1.sn2" />
     ...
     <SolutionItem Include="./Solution1.snl1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
     <MSBuild
        Projects="@(SolutionItem)"
        BuildInParallel="true"
        />
  </Target>
```

Copy the "Project ..." from an existing project file, to get the right ToolsVersion and xmlns.  See MSDN "MSBuild task" for additional options you can pass to the call to the MSBuild task.  To build, open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and, assuming the file above is named Build.proj, run this:

```
> msbuild Build.proj
```

...or for a detailed log...

```
> msbuild Build.proj /fl /flp;v=d;logfile=log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks spider the MSBuild part I kind of get, it is the deploying the solution to sharepoint that I am a little unsure about, can you help with that part specifically please?